# Boot Camp can't boot Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, boot, boot-camp

I just recently installed Windows 7 (Ultimate 64-bit) on my 15-inch Macbook Pro. Not long after I installed VMware Fusion 3. Windows runs perfectly on VMware and any other VM for that matter, but ever since, I am unable to boot Windows up alone. (Not sure if the problem is related, but just thought I should mention it)

Attempting to hold the Alt-Option key at start up gives me the two start-up disk choices, but picking either will boot Mac OS X anyways. And if I try to set the default disk to be the Windows one, the laptop is stuck in a constant loop where it tries to boot Windows, switches to Mac, restarts, tries to boot Windows, switches to Mac, restarts etc. until I Alt-Option or manually shut the computer down.

Help!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your Windows 7 disk may have a broken boot process. Trying following this guide to fix your issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt: Backup your Boot Camp partition with [Winclone](http://twocanoes.com/winclone/) reinstall Windows 7.